# jQuery on() Method

Tags: jquery, jquery-click-event

I can't make this work, I already read all i could find on the subject. Sure you can help me. 
   I simply need that the button with id "next" log on the console a random number when is clicked.. her is the html of the button:

```
<button id= "next" type= "button" class= "btn btn-lg col-xs-1">Quote!</button>
```

and here is the js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#next").on("click", function(){

        var randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random()*8)+1);

        console.log(randomNum);

    });

});
```

(I cut code for the sake of clarity).
Thanks!

Comment: What is not working? If you open up the developer console on the browser, do you see any errors? That code should work fine. How is the JavaScript added to the page?

Comment: Is the button dynamically created? If that is the case, use `$(document).on("click", "#next", function() {...` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#next").on("click", function(){

var randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random()*8)+1);

console.log(randomNum);

});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id= "next" type= "button" class= "btn btn-lg col-xs-1">Quote!</button>
```

Here you go. Seems to be working fine.
Make sure that you include JQuery before you call your code or you will receive a reference error. 
Happy coding!

http://codepen.io/IsabelInc/pen/vKppwO

Comment: I am assuming OP already has reference to the jQuery library as, if not, they would be complaining that `$ is undefined`

Comment: Sure. But this is exactly the code that OP used. Just made it into a snippet so that OP could see what was missing.

Comment: Thanks! I'm so dumb.. I hadn't put the jQuery reference.. :/